# altering jQuery UI datepicker format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I can't figure out how to change the date format from default *mm/dd/yyyy* to the European *dd/mm/yyyy*.

The manual states to use:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 26));
```

So far I have:

```
$('#next_date').datepicker();
```

which shows the calendar fine, but I'm not sure where the first line of code goes. This for example disables the calendar, nothing shows up, no JavaScript errors reported

```
$('#next_date').datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 26));
```

Answer (score 9):

I use this and it works fine

```
$('#next_date').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
```

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** i think i gave you code not for the jquery-ui datepicker. anyway, try this:

```
$('#next_date').datepicker({ altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

Comment: sorry, how would the yy-mm-dd get passed to the datepicker function? just this code doesnt do it

Comment: here we go

$("#last_date").datepicker({
       dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy'
  });

Answer (score 0):

dateFormat is returned to the input that datepicker is called on. altFormat and altField are another input altogether (in most cases hidden or shared)

Here is some sample code:

[IN HTML]

```
    <label for="display_date">Display/Start Date</label><br />

    <input type="text" class="dateStart" name="display_date" value="" /><br />

    <label for="display_date_end">End Date</label><br />

    <input type="text" class="dateEnd" name="display_date_end" value="" /><br />
```

[IN JAVASCRIPT INCLUDE]

```
    // set the datePicker on the start and end fields

    $('input.dateStart').datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd", changeYear: true});

    $('input.dateEnd').datepicker({

        dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd", 

        changeYear: true, 

        beforeShow: function(){

            var value = $(this).siblings('.dateStart').val();

            $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', value);

        }

    });
```